# Selenium WebDriver: Faster way to set values in many inputs

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am doing many tests, where I have to put values into 168 inputs fields in a table. At this moment, I am using for statement like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfValues + 1; i++) {
  try {
      findingElement.byXPath(".//*[@id='TDCON']/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[4]/span/span[2]/span/span/input").sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), value);
  }catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            break;
   }
}
```

It took ages to execute 40 tests similar to this. Is there any faster way using Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: CssSelector may be faster. Can you show HTML and URL of your application?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share any other information about application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time of execution is proportional to the number of commands executed. So to reduce it, you could select all the elements with a single call. You should also use a CSS selector rather than an XPath when it's possible:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(
  "#TDCON > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > span > span:nth-child(2) > span > span > input"));

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++) {
  try {
      elements[i].sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), value);
  }catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            break;
  }
}
```

Another way would be to inject a piece of Javascript and direcly assign the `.value` property:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
  "var cells = arguments[0].querySelectorAll('#TDCON > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)'); " +
  "var values = arguments[1]; " +
  "for(var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) { " +
  "  cells[i].querySelector('span > span:nth-child(2) > span > span > input').value = values[i]; " +
  "} "
  , findElement, values);
```

But it might not work if the typing is handled dynamically by the page.

Comment: Thanks, the first option looks good. I will try it, when I will be able to.